# Why I am getting Licenses error in SDL Tridion 2011?

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

We have renewed our `cd_licenses.xml` file and Tridion was accessible, but after some days we are getting this error:

> The license is invalid. Please contact SDL Tridion Customer Support: Error getting library  signature.
>   Unable to Initialize TDSE object.
>
> Licensing.StartupLicenseCheck Security.InitializeUserContext
>   UtilitiesTDS.GetUserContext TDSE.Initialize

Please help.

Answer (score 9):

You mention `cd_licenses.xml` but the TDSE object is specified in your error message, which sounds like it's from the Content Manager and you have also tagged Content Porter which, again, is on the Content Manager side. Did you also renew your `license.xml` file on your Content Manager?

From [the online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_3693BB92A3844A3E9F4D30FFC832C77B) 
([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

- `cd_licenses.xml` contains license keys for publishing content to the Content Delivery server using one or more transport protocols.
- `license.xml` contains license keys for the various Content Manager server software components

Failing that, I do not recall seeing an "Error getting library signature" before. I would suggest you verify that the license files are exactly as they were sent and have not had any extra characters/line breaks/encoding changes etc. added to them when they were deployed and then contact customer support.

Answer (score 6):

Have you removed the lock files after putting the new license in? Do a search for the lock files (search .ez* ) and remove all of them, then restart the server.

Answer (score 3):

Also check if hyper-threading is turned on. If it's a 6 core CPU it would in reality mean 12 core CPU with HT

Answer (score 2):

The error is on validating a license library, it’s unlikely to be an issue with the license itself.

- Validate the “..\Tridion\bin” folder is in the system Path variable.
- If not, add it (full path, not “..”).
- Search and remove the
  files called: ".ezl20ck" and ".ezlm20jk".
- Reboot the server.