# License file issue with Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013

I am getting below exception while browsing CME.

`Unable to get object: LicenseInfo Invalid license Error getting library signature.` I have verified that license file is correct. I have also replaced the license file with original one.

It is installed only 2 days before. Detailed exception occurs after passing credential for user authentication is:

System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault]: Unable to get object: LicenseInfo Invalid license Error getting library signature. (Fault Detail is equal to Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault).

Comment: seems to be duplicate of http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3537/why-i-am-getting-licenses-error-in-sdl-tridion-2011

Comment: Hi Raj Kumar,

I have not changed anything before starting error. To resolve the issue I have replaced the same file with original copy(Just to check if license file got corrupted).

I had already checked the link which you have provided. But there was no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is on validating a license library, it’s unlikely to be an issue with the license itself.

- Validate the “..\Tridion\bin” folder is in the system Path variable.
- If not, add it (full path, not “..”).
- Ensure the license you
  replaced with is valid for the server.
- Search and remove the
  files called: ".ezl20ck" and ".ezlm20jk".
- Reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

If this error comes, one more reason could be a Wrong version of JRE/JDK is installed on the server or the `JAVA_HOME` variable is pointing to the wrong location of JRE/JDK